org.hibernate.query.SemanticException in Spring query
I have this query:
List<AspectEs> findAllByProcessedIsTrueAndNatalIsOrSolarIs
            (Boolean processed, Integer natal, Integer solar);

But I have this error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.mysticriver.repository.AspectEsRepository.findAllByProcessedIsTrueAndNatalIsOrSolarIs(java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer); Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.lang.Integer' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Boolean'
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:106)

column definition:
  @Column(columnDefinition = "bit default 0 ")
    private Boolean processed;


Your method signature:
List<AspectEs> findAllByProcessedIsTrueAndNatalIsOrSolarIs
            (Boolean processed, Integer natal, Integer solar);

is inconsistent. The name implies that processed is equal to true, and at the same time there is a processed
parameter.
Do either this:
List<AspectEs> findAllByProcessedIsTrueAndNatalIsOrSolarIs
            (Integer natal, Integer solar);

or:
List<AspectEs> findAllByProcessedIsAndNatalIsOrSolarIs
            (Boolean processed, Integer natal, Integer solar);

However, you are mixing and and or conditions here, which will lead to the following evaluation order:
(processed = value and natal = value) or (solar = value)

That's probably not what you want.

What happens when you change Processed to anh Integer?

The error is occurring because the method signature findAllByProcessedIsTrueAndNatalIsOrSolarIs is not interpreted correctly by Spring Data JPA. The issue lies in the interpretation of the method name.
To properly express the logic of your query, you might want to use parentheses to group the conditions. Here's the corrected query method:
List findAllByProcessedIsTrueAnd(NatalIsIsTrueOrSolarIsTrue(Boolean processed, Integer natal, Integer solar);
Then, you would define custom query methods in your repository using @Query annotation to express the conditions properly:
@Query("SELECT a FROM AspectEs a WHERE a.processed = true AND (a.natal = :natal OR a.solar = :solar)")
List findAllByProcessedIsTrueAndNatalIsOrSolarIs(@Param("natal") Integer natal, @Param("solar") Integer solar);
This will correctly interpret the conditions and generate the query accordingly. Make sure you have @Query and @Param imported from org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query and org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param, respectively.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
